# RAM Usage is insane running a game

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

My system is Windows 7 Home Premium, i5-2320 proc, 8GB DDR3 1333Mhz RAM, Z77X-UD5H mobo, I have two HDDs, one is a 1TB and the other a small 288GB (250gb). Also, a new GPU, the R9 285.

Recently I’ve been having these very high amounts of RAM usage, when I play a game it can sometimes be from 4GB which is fine, but sometimes it’s at 7GB/8GB.  What are some things I should check?

The game is Battlefield 4, here is a pic

1st Picture: BF4 Running.
2nd Picture: After closing all programs including BF4.
3rd Picture: Fresh restart.

[image: RAM With BF4 Running]

[image: RAM Without BF4 Running]

[image: RAM after fresh restart]

This computer used to never have this much RAM in usage, I bought a new GPU and motherboard about two weeks ago. I used to run BF4 with a GTX 550Ti and the RAM never surpassed 6GB.

Comment: We need more information before we can help you. What operating system are you running?

Comment: what game? give a screenshot showing this usage

Comment: Still new to this, accidently "answered"  This is while running BF4, let me know what other info you need, I'll keep the game on for now. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t4b9zfzhww2tpg7/20141120_193556.jpg?dl=0

Comment: It looks like the game is meant to be using that insane amoutn of memory. According to this post by some guy http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2139695/battlefield-ram-usage.html    He has 2.45GB-2.85GB used by BF4 So compared to him you're doing very well!

Comment: Run RAMMap please, this tool shows more details about the memory usage: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx

Comment: I'll go ahead and use RAMMap, but can I ask, which tab do you want me to show?

Answer (score 3):

Video Games can consume large amounts of RAM, especially big box games. Really though, BF4 looks like it's running within reasonable limits. You should only be concerned if your machine is trying to swap RAM with a pagefile constantly.

Firefox and MBAM are using about 500MB alone. You have an scvhost running at 300MB. There are a lot of Windows services which run under a scvhost.exe instance, you would need to use a monitoring tool such as [Process Explorer from Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see which service that scvhost instance is holding. If I had to guess it's probably the Windows Update Service and/or Background Intelligent Transfer Service.

Comment: +1. Using RAM is a good thing. You want it all used where possible, unless you've A) got something more important to use it on, or B) its swapping to disk. In this case, looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Video games, especially the ones like BF4 eat up a lot of RAM.

Also, when you run a number of games, some might trigger background processes that remain even after you close the game. So that explains high RAM usage after playing a number of games.

Now, instead of restarting the PC to clear RAM, just log off and log on again. That should also do the same as restarting for all the processes started by that particular user account. And its faster!

Also, the lag has many reasons. Maybe, your hardware is getting too hot. In your case, the RAM seems to be the reason, but don't ignore the heating part. Too much heat causes lag.